# Download a file from git using requirements.txt

Tags: git, pip, requirements.txt

All I want is to download a .py file from git using the requirements.txt and in setup.py and make it available for other repos. It shouldn't be specific to any commits. Only the latest should be downloaded in specified path. Don't need to install anything.

Here's what I have (for eg:)

```
https://git.myorg.com/it/xyz/abc/-/raw/develop/myfile.py
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that is not possible. You will need to have the files needed for a small python package in your git and then point pip to installing the git instead of an individual py file.

Comment: What does "from git", or "specified path" mean? What are the roles of `requirements.txt` and `setup.py` in this context? `requirement.txt` is just a text file it can not download things. What do you want to do, what have you tried? Can you produce a [mre]? This question is not clear at all...

Comment: @sinoroc from git refers to GitLab. Obviously requirement.txt does have any capability to download things by itself. Usually, we use it with pip command. E.g. pip install requirements.txt. What I want to do is clearly stated at the very beginning "All I want is to download a .py file from git using the requirements.txt..". 
What I have in my requirements.txt in an attempt to achieve this is also provided in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `requirements.txt` syntax won't let you specify just an individual file, but it will let you specify a package to install from a Git repo. The syntax lets you specify the commit to use, or the branch, but if you leave that out it will just clone the latest, as you want.

So my solution would be to create a minimalist package that contains just your desired file. Create its own setup.py as usual, and then refer to it by url.

Let's call you package `my_package`, say it's at `https://server/path/my_package.git`, then you can have this line in your `requirements.txt` file where you need to use it:

```
-e git+https://server/path/my_package.git#egg=my_package
```

Some other examples:

- install the latest in branch `my_branch`:

  ```
  -e git+https://server/path/my_package.git@my_branch#egg=my_package
  ```
- install specifically from commit `sha1`:

  ```
  -e git+https://server/path/my_package.git@sha1#egg=my_package
  ```

And then when you want to use it, you'll have to import it with `from my_package import my_file`